# Is there possibility to forward content from WhatsApp to our application using business api?

Tags: whatsapp

Is it possible to use the WhatsApp business API to communicate with users and also allow them to  forward content from WhatsApp directly to our application. For example enabling Web-hooks for different WhatsApp channels to receive the messages from those channels. If yes, can someone guide me how can we implement this feature?  and how can we authorize those channels with our WA business account

Finding sources/documentation for developing needed feature

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. The WhatsApp Business Platform allows medium and large businesses to communicate with their customers at scale. Using their APIs, businesses can connect thousands of agents and bots to interact with customers programmatically and manually. Additionally, the APIs can be integrated with numerous backend systems, such as CRM and marketing platforms

Here is the link for the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/overview

Link for different types of webhooks:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/webhooks

There are multiple ways given in the documentation. But keep in mind, do read the documentation carefully, they have their updated and the previous version so use them as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Whatsapp API allows you to Broadcast messages to Unlimited Users, automate notifications, integrate Chatbots, provide Live Chat on Multiple devices and many more functions. Install the WhatsApp Business API Client and then Install your API client. Once your client is working, you can update your application settings. Start using the client, Register your phone number with an API call to /account and send a test message with a call to /messages . let me know if u find this helpful.